# Zebble: 'Drawing.Line' does not contain a definition for 'Id'

Tags: xamarin-zebble, zebble

I'm trying to use Zebble.Drawing in my UWP project but the project doesn't build with this error: 'Drawing.Line' does not contain a definition for 'Id'. Here's the code for my Zebble page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<z-Component z-type="ActionBar" z-base="Page" z-namespace="UI.Pages"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./../.zebble-schema.xml">

  <Stack Style.Margin.Top="10" Style.Margin.Left="5">
    <Drawing>
      <Drawing.Line></Drawing.Line>
    </Drawing>
  </Stack>
</z-Component>
```

And here's the line in .zebble-generated.cs file that causes the error:

```
var __drawing_Line1 = new Drawing.Line { Id = "__drawing_Line1" };
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. The Id has been added to the Line drawing and will be available in next release. Meanwhile, you can use the source code available in following GitHub repository:
https://github.com/Geeksltd/Zebble.Drawing